# CakePHP 2.X - Couple of questions on HasMany Relation

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm having some problems using this old framework I had to manage.

I have these tables:

- GROUP   -> HAS MANY -> MONITOR
- MONITOR -> HAS MANY -> [ EVENTS , ZONE ]
- MONITOR -> HAS_AND_BELONGS_TO_MANY -> GROUP

For GROUP -> MONITOR Relationship, a join tables has been created by Cake called GROUP_MONITOR.

This is the HasMany Configuration on Group Model:

```
'Monitor' => array(
'className' => 'Monitor',
'joinTable' =>  'Groups_Monitors',
'foreignKey' => 'GroupId',
'associationForeignKey' => 'MonitorId',
```

**QUESTION 1:**

I'm trying to retrieve all groups with all the related monitors. I found the recursive key that allow to go deeply in relations:

```
$all_groups  = $this->Group->find('all', array('recursive' => 1));
```

I got this error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Monitor.GroupId' in 'field list'"

It seems like Cake is not using the "Groups_Monitors" table but is searching groupId in the Monitor Table;

**QUESTION 2:**

Trying to get Groups querying Monitors, with recursive to 1 I got all groups correctly but also all other Monitor's HasMany relations.

```
$all_monitors = $this->Monitor->find('all',array("recursive" => 1));
```

Is it possible to exclude some HasMany relations in find to have a reduced amount of data?

Answer (score 0):

You say you have

```
GROUP -> HAS MANY -> MONITOR
```

"Has many" doesn't use a join table. The way this relation works is "monitor" has to have a foreign key that references a group. If you want to use the join table you should use "has and belongs to many".

For Q2, use the containable behavior. You'll be able to specify in detail what data and which models you want fetched from the DB. https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answer. Im still having problem with question 2. With: $this->Monitor->find('all') I got only Monitor. $this->Monitor->find('all', array("recursive" => 0)) I got Monitor and MonitorStatus that is AsOne relation. With recusrive => 1 I got ALL relations (Group too). I have added 'contain' => array ("Group") to get ONLY Group but it still give me ALL

Comment: Do you mean you're querying Monitors and expecting to get only Groups?

Comment: Yeah. Some way to specify which joins do. But from your question I suppose is not possible.

Comment: If you're interested in Groups, you should use Group to run the query, using Monitor just confuses things.

Comment: Using Groups is what I was trying to do but unfortunally, the original programmer of ZoneMinder, the software Im writing a Plugin for, has chosen a HasMany relations and I cant modify it.

Comment: what's stopping you from changing `$this->Monitor->find` to `$this->Group->find`? You're just trying to get a list of groups regardless of their relation to a specific monitor(s) right?

Comment: No exactly. I was trying to get All groups with all their related Monitors. But with HasMany it seems, as you said, it not possible so I had to get All monitors and find their related groups. But this query return all the Monitor's relationship I don't need and that make query more heavy.

Comment: I see. The way your database is set up, `GROUP -> HAS MANY -> MONITOR` is incorrect. You have to change it to `GROUP -> HAS_AND_BELONGS_TO_MANY -> MONITOR`. Then you can use the group->monitor relation.